# Apex rest service issue with HTTP Post method when i Access from Postman

Tags: rest, apexrest, httprequest, httppost, postman

i created Apex rest service and `@HttpPost` method , i am able call POST method & got data in request body successfully from workbench. but i had issue with when i try to access from Post man.

i got error with 405 method not allowed.

```
{
    "errorCode": "METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED",
    "message": "HTTP Method 'GET' not allowed. Allowed are POST"
}
```

if i change @HttpPost annotation to @HttpGet i am able to call method & access the request data successfully.
NOTE: i am accessing Salesforce via Connected App & Oauthflow
why only @HttpPost Methods got opposed?

Comment: That’s working per designed. You can use GET request only if you annotate with @HttpGet and use POST when you annotate with at HttpPost

Answer (score 1):

405 is for "The request method doesn't have a corresponding Apex method."
The method is correctly declared by @HttpPost annotation. This helps in sending large content via post body instead of the URL. Postman, there is a problem , if it gets 301 or 302 from Salesforce (a redirect directive), it redirects with a GET Method. So in a nutshell, you should test using the interface/device that you are planning to use in Production to access your Apex Rest Service.

Comment: Ran into this when the URL was specified with `https://`; SF redirected to the secure endpoint, and Postman silently changed it into a GET.  Worse, if you have "automatically follow redirects" turned on (the default), it doesn't tell you it was redirected.  It's not even reported in the Postman Console.